# Ping, SSH failed in VM and host machine

Tags: ssh, networking, firewall, vmware, ping

In VMware

- from Centos to other VM and windows host ->ping and ssh not working(prompt does not say anything,it goes to timeout)
- from Centos  -> google ping is ok,
- from  other VM to Centos -> ping, ssh is also ok
- vm centos and windows host (192.168.1.*) vm redhat and vm fedora (192.168.20.*)
  all vm has ens160

sshd on,firewalld off,static routing does not help.

What might be the issue with my centos vm?

Comment: sorry not to mention before. Centos also a vm (192.168.1 network).windows host 192.168.1 network.other vm redhat and fedora both 198.168.20 network. all are using ens160 adapter.i can connect redhat/fedora to centos but not vice verca.

Comment: Please put that in your question. Make out easy for people to read and understand the problem. You've just mentioned RedHat too. Make it absolutely clear which machines are VM, Host, and Other

Comment: can you edit your question with result of `ip r s` ( or `route print -4`  for windows) on all VM ? are all VM on same VLAN (select a VM => edit setting => Network Adapter) ?

Comment: @Archemar that's kind of explain it.redhat and fedora were using NAT and were in other vlan.now that i have changed redhat to bridged adapter, centos-redhat-windows can communicate eachother. but  they can not connect to fedora(it's using NAT and in other vlan). but fedora can ping to other vlan(all those  using bridge centos-redhat-host ). My theoretical knowledge is very minimal.

Comment: i think port forwarding in NAT might solve all the problems.though i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add a static route on the CentOS that you want to connect to the network.

Comment: Added a route in routing table, unfortunately not working. Could it be something related to port or firewall?i don't have much knowledge about it